# How to pass java file name as parameter to method?

Tags: android

```
public void generateOTP(String MobileNo,**??????**) {
Call<**RegisterMerchantModelResponse**> call = otpApi.generateOtp(otpModel);
}
```

when i call this method i have to pass javafile name as parameter.This method is call from a activity.This **generateOTP** define in another class.

```
generateOTP("1234567890",**RegisterMerchantModelResponse**)
```

What i have to write in the place of **??????** in method definition that i will replace with **RegisterMerchantModelResponse** in Call<**RegisterMerchantModelResponse**> call = otpApi.generateOtp(otpModel);.
Please tell me about this.

Comment: If ?????? is a class name in you application package, it should be accessible by package_name.class_name

Comment: I have to write like:-- public void generateOTP(String MobileNo,string package_name.class_name ) {
Call<package_name.class_name> call = otpApi.generateOtp(otpModel);
}                                                                                                                                                                       It will work??package_name.class_name  may be another class name.

Comment: I am doing like this:-- public void generateOTP(String MobileNo,Context cls ) { Call<cls> call = otpApi.generateOtp(otpModel); }                                 But its not working.cls may be  another classname.

Comment: Hey any one here to give answer of my question?

Comment: Do you want to pass `android.content.Context` instead of RegisterMerchantModelResponse ? or want to pass a String ?

Comment: RegisterMerchantModelResponse is a class name.What type of parameter i have to write in the method.                                                        generateOTP method call from another class with two parameter one is phone number and another is class name.                                                      I need to know what type of parameter i have to define in method.              Please help me..

Comment: I have to put that parameter in the below code.                    Call<parameter> call = otpApi.generateOtp(otpModel);

Comment: Look for Source code or documentation of class which is referenced by "otpApi" and find the generateOtp method,  that is the usual way you will find it's parameters. I cannot answer unless I know which class you are referencing by "otpApi"

Comment: I am doing like this                                                                                OtpApi otpApi = ValuesUtility.mRetrofit.create(OtpApi.class);
OtpModel otpModel = new OtpModel();                                                           Call<parameter> call = otpApi.generateOtp(otpModel);                                         I don't know what type of parameter define in method definition.                         Parameter contain the class name.

Comment: Seems like almost no helpful documentation is provided on Internet. You will need to decompile it(OtpApi.class) or open it in class viewer,then you can find it's parameters. Extract the OtpApi.class from the library jar you are using.

Comment: OK thanks bro.....